# Is this limit of sums of product over the primes bounded by the square root function?

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, limsup-and-liminf, products

Is it true that the square root always bounds this sum:
$$\sqrt{n} \ge \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \,\Biggr\lvert \sum_{m=1}^{n} \prod_{k \in \mathbb{P}}^{\infty} \Biggl(1-2 \biggl(\frac{\sin(\pi\,m)}{k \sin(\pi\frac{m}{k})}\biggr)^2\Biggr)\cdot\Biggl(1-\biggl(\frac{\sin(\pi\, m)}{k^2 \sin(\pi\frac{m}{k^2})} \biggr)^2\Biggr) \Biggl \lvert$$

I would really appreciate an answer, as I might use this for a paper I am writing (In the case that this is true). And I do hope that you can help me with this. $$$$
(If this is (not) true, could you please explain why)

Comment: The product in the right hand side is trivially $1$, because $\sin(\pi m)=0$ for $m\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: i thought so too at first, but you are also dividing by zero, and the limit is equal to 1, so for every $k^2=m$, the right hand side is 0.

Comment: I think you have to explicit what do you mean by $\sin(\pi m)/\sin(\pi m/k)$ when $k\mid m$.

Comment: well, i have kind of disguised a limit question in there; as the $sin( \pi m)$ is obviously always for every m, but if you divide that by $k \times sin( \frac{\pi m}{k})$ (which is also zero every time k divides m, the expression equals to 1

Comment: Then you are asking$$\sqrt{n} \ge \,\Biggr\lvert \sum_{m=1}^{n} \prod_{k \in \mathbb{P}}^{\infty} (1-2 \sigma(m,k))\cdot (1-\sigma(m,k^2)) \Biggl \lvert$$
where
$$\sigma(m,k)=\begin{cases}1&k\mid m\\0&k\nmid m\end{cases}$$

Comment: yes, this is basically the same

Comment: What's $\Bbb P$?

Comment: I used this symbol for the Primes.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$\sigma(m,p)=\begin{cases}1&p\mid m\\0&p\nmid m\end{cases}$$
First note that
\begin{align}
\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^{\infty} (1-2 \sigma(m,p))&=\prod_{p\mid m} (-1)\\
\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^{\infty}(1-\sigma(m,p^2))&=|\mu(m)|
\end{align}
Consequently,
$$\prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^{\infty} (1-2 \sigma(m,p))(1-\sigma(m,p^2))=\mu(m)$$
the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).
Then
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n} \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}}^{\infty}(1-2 \sigma(m,p))(1-\sigma(m,p^2))=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\mu(m)=M(n)$$
is the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function).
So you are asking $|M(n)|\leq\sqrt n$ as $n\to+\infty$, <strike>which is not known today</strike>, that's the *Mertens Conjecture*.

Comment: thank you so much, I had this lying around and forgot what it was related to. I just had the formula and below it: If true, proves the Riemann Hypothesis. So I posted it here to try and gain some insight. Again thank you a lot. This has been bothering me for the last couple of weeks.

Comment: It is not know today? I think, I read somewhere that this the Mertens Conjecture is wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right: see [here](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/mertens.disproof.pdf)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture